# Run a script command from one server on another

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a go daddy account and also a vps in germany. In my vps, I run a code script (we will call it codegen).

When I run `./codegen`, I am asked how many codes I want to make and with that answer on the screen, my codes are there and at the same time are put in a file called `/var/etc/codes.cfg`.

Great! But I want this file linked from a script I have on godaddy.

I can run the script codegen OK on godaddy and of course can make a file called codes.cfg, but as this is not on my vps, it's pointless as the codes can't be used for access as my program is on my vps and scans that code.cfg every minute for new codes to allow.

So, how can I link godaddy to my vps to run codegen?

I was guessing that codegen can be run from within another script.
so I added this to another script i have:

```
return shell_exec(__DIR__ . "/codegen $arg");
```

How can I change the above to run from ssh or login from go daddy to vps?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you really want. Using proper capitalization and punctuation and writing complete sentences is not luxus :-)

Answer (score 0):

### how can i link godaddy to my vps to run codegen?

I agree the question is not that clearly phrased. I am interpreting it to mean that you have a godaddy environment and you have a separate virtual machine which contains some script that you want to execute in your godaddy environment.

You either have to pass the command to execute through SSH (piping your command through SSH, so that you execute the piped SSH command on your godaddy server and it is executed on your remote server.. in that case you probably also need an SSH key.

Or if you don't want to pipe your command through SSH, then you need to establish some kind of common pathing between the two server I.E NFS mount or similiar. This option might be hard to get working with a godaddy server.